# Detect if objects are loaded [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, image-preloader

I was wondering, is there a way to detect if a certain image / div is loaded?
For example when i am loading two heavy images and showing a loading sign at the two places the images will later occupy, is there a way to already display the first image when it's loaded while still loading the second one?

Comment: When the image is done 'loading' and ready to be displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myImage.addEventListener('load', function() { ... }, false);
```

Code inside the above function will be called when the image is finished loading.

Comment: True - as long as it hasn't finished loading BEFORE this line of JavaScript executes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `new Image` to preload images, then you can do the following to be notified of then it is loaded

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    //display the image
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "%3Cimg src='myimg.jpg' alt=''/%3E";
};
img.src = "myimg.jpg";
```

Remember to set the `src` *after* the `onload`.

Answer (score 0):

if an image is done loading, its `.complete` property switches to true.